Python package with multiple requirement files
I am looking to create a python package but it contains multiple requirement files. different modules use different environments. for example:

What would be the optimal way to create a package. The requirement files contains long list of packages. creating a single list is not possible. Infect for example, different modules use different versions of python. Should I add them as extra dependencies?
